# Azure Event Grid - discovered expired events?

Tags: azure-eventgrid, expirationhandler

I was wondering if there is any way to take actions on expired Azure Event Grid event delivery?  A couple use cases, 1) simply log the fact an event wasn't delivered, 2) create the equivalent of a dead letter queue.

I couldn't find anything in the APIs for notification or polling for expired event delivery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Event Grid failed retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749654/azure-event-grid-failed-retries)

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086169/4167200

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything at the moment. A dead-letter queue will be coming soon along with other configurable options for delivery.

Comment: Could you describe more info about these delivery options?

Comment: An alternative to a dead-letter queue might be an  'endpoint of last resort.' An endpoint where event deliveries that are expiring are sent, wrapped by a meta information about source, destination, retry attempts, etc.

Comment: My understanding is that it's still in the planning phases but a dead-letter queue and possibly ways to configure the frequency of delivery is possible.